# How to get a range of arrays

Tags: php, arrays, string, explode

I have a code which I have to explode my text using "*" as a delimiter.

I have a pattern that always the array [0] and [1] will be excluded and the rest of them need to be included inside a variable, but my problem is that I don't know how to catch dynamically the rest of the arrays that I have to put them all together inside of it.

Specially because my text may have more "*" and explode into more parts, but I have to get them all together. Excluding the [0] and [1]

```
$item= explode("*",$c7);

        print_r($item);

//so now that I know which are my [0] and [1] arrays I need to get the rest of them inside of another variable

$variable = ?? //the rest of the $item arrays
```

Comment: Could you please provide an example string with expected output?

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew yes, I'll post it right now

Comment: So, from `a*b*c*d*e` you need to get `c*d*e`? Then, Jakub's answer should work for you.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew yes, exactly this kind of thing that I need. I'll try to use it and then I'll give the feedback.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
$str = 'a*b*c*d*e';
$newStr = implode('*', array_slice(explode('*', $str), 2)); // OUTPUT: c*d*e
```

[explode()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.explode.php) is used to chunk the string by a delimiter

[implode()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.implode.php) is used to build a string again from chunks

[array_slice()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-slice.php) is used to select a range of the elements

Comment: I think it should be `$newStr = implode('*', array_slice(explode('*', $str), 2));` but not sure.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew, yes, the author didn't specify before that the result should be separated back with the delimited.

Answer (score 1):

I realise an answer was already accepted, but [`explode`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.explode.php) has a third argument for this, and with [`end`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.end.php) you can grab that last, non-split part:

```
$str = 'a*b*c*d*e';
$res = end(explode("*", $str, 3));
```

`$res` gets this value as a result:

```
c*d*e
```

Answer (score 0):

I think based off of your question, if I interpreted it correctly something like below will be useful.

**USING A LOOP**

```
$str = "adssa*asdASD*AS*DA*SD*ASD*AS*DAS*D";
$parts = explode("*", $str);

$newStr = "";
for ($i = 2; $i < count($parts); ++$i) {
    $newStr .= $parts[$i];
}
```

Comment: The proper operator would be .= otherwise you get 0 (zero) on php 7